# Teradata SQL to Extract Records Based on Approximate String Matching

Tags: teradata, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy, metaphone

We are on version TD 14 and I come from Netezza / Postgre(Redshift) background. I have been asked to extract a login data from audit logs to find out records/transactions where the same ip is submitting similar looking usernames with small changes. e.g  Samir --> Samr  --> Amir etc
To capture phishing activity.
In POstgres we have fuzzy string functions like '%'  e.g ColA % ColB (where % operator is equivalent to Similar)
Soundex, Metaphone, levenshtein etc.
In  Teradata however I have just encountered or I have been able to find just Soundex. Is there any such in built function/method capability with Teradata version 14 to achieve the above string approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata 14.x supports the Damerau-Levenshtein Distance algorithm via the `EDITDISTANCE()` function and n-gram pattern matching via the `NGRAM()` function.

You can find information about the EDITDISTANCE function [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.051.html) and the NGRAM() function [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.132.html).